# Draw the sketch of $y=x^3-6x^2+9x-1$

Tags: functions

$$y=x^3-6x^2+9x-1$$
$$y=x(x-3)^2-1$$
min (3,-1), max (1, 3)
inflection point (2,1)

Cuts Oy for x=0, y=-1. What about when it cuts Ox, y gets irrational values. How can I draw it precisely?

Comment: What do you mean by "precisely"? If you just want a representative sketch, then the properties you mentioned about the curve will give you the sketch.

Comment: The $x$ intercept is hard to compute, just drop it. You can compute extra points for some simple values of $x$.

Comment: @ShraddheyaShendre I thought if there way a way to build the sketch using displacement of the graphic

Comment: Why do you say there is a minimum at $(3, -1)$? The function has no minimum; just consider the limit as $x \to -\infty$.

Comment: @jacer21 - The OP meant local minimum (quite obviously)

Comment: @Shraddheya Shendre Oops. You're right. My bad

Answer (score 0):

You can build on your idea of using translation of graphs. One can easily sketch the graph of $y = x(x-3)^2$ using the following:

(1) Roots are o, 3, 3 (will touch the X-axis at $(3,0)$).

(2) Local maxima: $(1,4)$ and local minima: $(3,0)$.

(3) Point of inflection: $(2,2)$.

(4) Passes through the origin.

Then you can shift the whole sketch by 1 units down to obtain the required sketch. Unfortunately, you will lose track of the original roots after this.